# What is this TSQL ".."

Tags: t-sql

I've googled and looked through the MSDN TSQL Reference but haven't been able to find a definition or explanation on what "**..**" means or does.

***example***

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null
drop table #temp
```

Your help in explaining or a referential resource on what ".." and how it is used would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a shorthand for telling the database to use the default schema name (`dbo`).

> That just means that the default schema (dbo) should be used. In other words:
>
> ```
> Customers..FirstName
> ```
>
> is the same thing as
>
> ```
> Customers.dbo.FirstName
> ```

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic585446-338-1.aspx

Comment: I found and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563(v=sql.105).aspx) is the MSDN Reference containing the definition: